# MOSFET parasitic signal? (parasitic triggeried millivolts, can be thermal noise - how to prevent?)

Tags: mosfet, noise

I have a MOSFET that is closed, but even in closed position I sometimes can see some very very small signal from it.

How can I make a barrier to prevent this small signal?
If I put an diode? It must make a 0.5-0.7V barrier - but it don't prevent this noise.

This MOSFET is used for NMR impulse on very sensitive coils, cause then it is closed - it must be closed, even 4kTR/3 is not okay. Is it possible to not use a relay and make some barrier for the MOSFET?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the noise is getting from supply. Cannot it be just some induced voltage on wires? Try to place a 1k resistor across load.

Comment: Don't use the words "closed" and "open" here; they're ambiguous. Use "on" and "off" instead. In electrical contexts they mean the opposite of what they do in most contexts, and I suspect the opposite of what you mean. Your MOSFET is on the wrong side of the supply to be an effective switch; as it is right now, there's no way to turn it off--the body diode will conduct.

Comment: @Hearth That's a PFET, used as a high side switch, but drawn unconventionally which is extremely confusing - I thought the same as you first. The load node will be floating when FET is off, which may explain noise.

Comment: @Justme I'm so used to seeing people using NFETs incorrectly I didn't even think this one could be a PFET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet shows a maximum zero gate voltage drain current of -0.1mA.  If that's too much for your application, you need to pick a different MOSFET.

Comment: Q1-Base, it only takes 0.6V of noise to turn it on.  
M1-Gate takes maybe 4V to turn it on a little.  
I think Q1 is more likely to turn on with noise.

Comment: @ronsimpson Your comment does not fit my answer since my answer talks about the case where gate and source are shortcircuited.  There is no external noise source in that case and still, according to the data sheet, drain current.

Comment: is it possible to make branch so that the current less than the threshold goes to another load?

Comment: Ty, have found in datasheet "Zero Gate Voltage Drain Current" and it is really to high for this application (25-250 uA)

Comment: @ViacheslavPopika You can add another NPN transistor with a current-limiting emitter resistor as a current dump, with the base connected to the MOSFET gate and the collector to the drain.  The current-limiting is for the transition period.  Problem, of course, is that the resistor has to be significantly smaller than the cold resistance of the bulb, or you don't lower the voltage significantly.  It's easier to dump extra current if you have some negative voltage rail to dump it to.